# My login is not working. I used in code username and password for it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my first login with android. The IF Condition is not working properly. When i give the correct password and username it exec the else part.Need help in this.

I can't see any errors in the code since i'm new to android studio. I used Latest android version (Pie) and Lolipop to test. same error happens.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText Name;
private EditText Password;
private TextView info;
private Button login;
private int counter = 5;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    info.setText("No of Attempts remaining : 5");
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private void validate (String username, String userPassword){

    if ((username == "Admin") && (userPassword == "admin")){
        Intent Intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(Intent);
    }
    else
    {

        counter --;
        info.setText("No of Attempts remaining :" + String.valueOf(counter));
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                login.setEnabled(false);
            }
    }
}
```

}

I expect when the correct login info is given the app should go to SecondActivity.class .But actually it's not proceeding to SecondActivity with the correct details too.

Comment: You need to use `if (username.equals("admin") && userPassword.equals("admin"))`

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you !!

Comment: Read about difference between equals and ==. It's really important to know and a little confused if you are starting with java